# Google OAuth2 Library Issue WIth Storyboard IOS

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, uistoryboard

I am facing this issue of trying to initWithScope for the GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch and trying to push it out using PresentModalViewController.

My project have StoryBoard enable.

When i try to push i will have a SIGBRT error. It seems that the initWithScope doesnt gel very well with the PresentModal View.

However, I did try to init:nil bundle:nil this actually works but shows nothing as the parameters was not provider by me to the Controller.

Can anyone please advice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it would be helpful but I have the same problem recently with the GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch of the first version (no OAuth 2) using XCode 4.2 and iOS 5.0 SDK with storyboards on a simple view, changing even the call to presentModalViewController: to push this GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch and see the login page of my website OAuth service with out any success until I realize that the google code depends on the navigation controller, so I embedded my view inside a Navigation Controller and it work flawlessly :)